# Google geocoder service is not returning appropriate lat and long values with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google map is not showing the exact location. I'm taking the address from our clients and will display them the map. I cross checked the google lat and long with mine, it is not returning the exact values. Here is my code, if I am wrong, please guide me.

```
function callMap() {

    var fullAddress = address + "," + city + "," + state + "," + zip;
    var lat_Company = "";
    var lng_Company = "";
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': fullAddress
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            lat_Company = parseFloat(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
            lng_Company = parseFloat(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
            var lCompanyObject = new Object();
            lCompanyObject.Name = companyDetails.CompanyName;
            lCompanyObject.Description = address + "<br/>" + city + ", " + state + "," + zip;
            lCompanyObject.FullAddress = address + ", " + city + ", " + state + "," + zip;
            lCompanyObject.Lat = lat_Company;
            lCompanyObject.Lng = lng_Company;
            displayCompany(city, state, "comp_map", "mapinfowindow", lCompanyObject, "fromSideBar");
        }
    });
    var abpoutsideBarBuilder = '<ul>' +
        '<li><div id="map_wrapper1">' +
        '<div id="comp_map1"></div>' +
        '<div id="mapinfowindow"style="display:none" ><b>#name</b><br>#description</div></div></li></ul>';
    $('.about_map_addr_businesshours').html(abpoutsideBarBuilder);
}

function displayCompany(pCity, pState, pMapDiv, mapinfowindow, lCompany, from) {
    var requestLocation = lCompany.FullAddress;
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': requestLocation
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var lat = parseFloat(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
            var lng = parseFloat(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
            if (lat != null && lng != null) {
                centerLat = lat;
                centerLng = lng;
                initDisplayMap(centerLat, centerLng, pMapDiv, mapinfowindow, lCompany, from);
            }
        } else {
            console.error("Geocode was not successful for the following reason ::" + status);
        }
    });
}

function initDisplayMap(pCenterLat, pCenterLng, pMapDiv, mapinfowindow, pCompany, from) {
    if ($("#" + mapinfowindow).length > 0) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pCenterLat, pCenterLng);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: latlng,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            navigationControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(pMapDiv), myOptions);

        var infowindow = null;
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
        var LatLngList = new Array();


        var marker = pCompany;
        var markerHTML = $('#mapinfowindow').clone().html();

        if (from.indexOf("fromSideBar") != -1) {
            markerHTML = markerHTML.replace("#name", marker.Name);
            markerHTML = markerHTML.replace("#description", marker.Description);
        } else if (from.indexOf("fromAboutBar") != -1) {
            markerHTML = markerHTML.replace("#name", marker.Name);
            markerHTML = markerHTML.replace("#description", marker.Description);
        }

        if (marker.Lat != null && marker.Lng != null) {
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.Lat, marker.Lng);
            LatLngList[LatLngList.length] = myLatLng;

            var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                clickable: true,
                html: markerHTML
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(beachMarker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            if (LatLngList.length > 1) {
                for (var i = 0, LtLgLen = LatLngList.length; i < LtLgLen; i++) {
                    //  And increase the bounds to take this point
                    bounds.extend(LatLngList[i]);
                }
                //Fit these bounds to the map 
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
                map.setZoom(map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
                map.setCenter(beachMarker.getPosition());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any example of "wrong" coordinates from Google? How can you tell Google is wrong and you are not? And where do you get your coordinates from?

Comment: My code returns this latandlng value = -26.1432825,28.01771980000001.
I searched for the same address in Google Maps and got the latandlong from the url  -26.143706,28.020766.May be the decimals value is different but in Map its showing three streets before the actual address.

Comment: Ok so you mean that the coordinates from a specific place you search on maps.google.com are different than the coords returned by the geocoder. Please confirm. And what did you search to get the above results? We can't guess everything. We are not in your brain! :)

Comment: Yeah,A random search, this the address of I searched in maps.google.com
Nakedcherry Waxing Boutique
6th Street
Parkhurst,South Africa.Google maps are showing the exact one,with my code, showing the 6th st 3rd Ave but the actual address is in 6th st 2nd Ave

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code? Using a simple geocoder and searching for *Nakedcherry Waxing Boutique* returns ZERO_RESULTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix up geocoder an places.

> **Nakedcherry Waxing Boutique** 6th Street Parkhurst,South Africa

the bold part of this string obviously isn't a address-component.

Expecting the desired result is as when I would expect to get my location for a query like

> **Dr.Molle**,Berlin,Germany

The result you get by the geocoder is for 6th Street Parkhurst,South Africa, and the result is correct.

When you look for a place use the places-textsearch, the result for the given query will be: `-26.1437060,28.0207660`

Comment: Okay,I assume that from your answer,should I use Google places Api for this? If so I won't be knowing customer address right weather he will be entering places or normal address.Can you suggest me which one to use and how it will work.

Comment: I would suggest to use the places-textSearch when you don't know the type of the input. The documentation may be found at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests

Comment: Thank you very much,cleared confusion.one more doubt,how to get the latitude and longitude values. Through Geocoder?,If so, its not returning the exact values,by using those value the in places-textsearch will also show wrong place,I guess.please help me :(

Comment: the textSearch will return  the coordinates, take a look at `geometry.location` for the returned PlaceResult

Comment: Sorry to trouble you again,one more doubt how to will we get the lat and long values while requesting the textSearch service we should mention the lat and long i.e., textSearch(request,callback); and when we use this it will return list of locations that match, but I want unique location. how to do, I searched but I didn't get.

Comment: There is no unique location(even geocoding may return multiple results)